# Apache Jmeter HTTP Header Manager override "Host" Header without appending the port

Tags: jmeter, http-headers, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm trying to load test a service which needs a specific "Host" header to route. (and also this service is running on port 9211). In Jmeter config, I added a "Http header manager" and added an override for the said header. But the request seems to have the port appended in the host header like following. I believe this could be a bug in jmeter(or some weird feature). In any case is there a way around this?

I want the "Host" header to be "my-host" and that only without appending the port.

jmeter config

[image: jmeter config]

Heder manager setup

[image: Heder manager setup]

Actual request headers

[image: actual request headers]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is something you can configure, it's being done under [HTTPHC4Impl.setConnectionHeaders() function](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java#L1395), the port is being added for "non-default" ports (80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS)

Actually it doesn't contradict with the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.4) so I would recommend just ignoring it.

However if you have a specific use case and need to send the [Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header without specifying the port - you will need to switch the "Client implementation" of the HTTP Request sampler to `Java`, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or better use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) if you want the setting to be applied to all HTTP Request samplers)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for. Worked..!!